# How can I get two interface from

Tags: json, mat-table

I try to transform HTTP response to TypeScript interface.

Server sends:

```
{
"cantidadRegistros": {
    "cantidad": 12
},
"listaEntidades": [
    {
        "idestado": 206,
        "nombreestado": "Anulado",
        "habilitado": "Si"
    },
    {
        "idestado": 202,
        "nombreestado": "Apertura",
        "habilitado": "Si"
    },
    {
        "idestado": 203,
        "nombreestado": "Asignado",
        "habilitado": "Si"
    },
    {
        "idestado": 213,
        "nombreestado": "Cerrado",
        "habilitado": "Si"
    },
    {
        "idestado": 210,
        "nombreestado": "En desarrollo",
        "habilitado": "Si"
    },
    {
        "idestado": 209,
        "nombreestado": "En espera de AyP",
        "habilitado": "No"
    }
]
}
```

and my interface are:

```
import { EstadoInterface } from './EstadoInterface';
import { CantidadRegistrosInterface } from './CantidadRegistrosInterface';

export interface EstadoInterfacePaginado {
cantidadRegistros: CantidadRegistrosInterface;
listaEntidades: EstadoInterface[];
}

export interface CantidadRegistrosInterface {
cantidad: number;
}

import { GenericInterface } from 'src/app/interfaces/GenericInterface';
export interface EstadoInterface extends GenericInterface {

idestado:number;
nombreestado:String;
habilitado:String;
}
```

My class method is:

```
public getAll() {
    this.subscriptions.add(
        this.estadosService.getAllPaginado(this.pagina, this.cantidadRegistros, this.campo, this.orden)
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.dataSource.data = res as EstadoInterfacePaginado[];
            })
    );
```

and I'll take to object

1. cantidadRegistros
2. listaEntidades

because listaEntidades it's my datasource.data of MatTable.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using Object.keys like

```
                Object.keys(res).map(key => {
                    this.can=res['cantidadRegistros'];
                    this.eip=res['listaEntidades'];
                });
```

After that, I have two interface and I can works with them isolated.